# Shading part of a sector of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, two concentric circles centered at the origin are drawn. How do I get the sector of the big circle between 225 degrees and 315 degrees and outside the smaller circle shaded?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%\draw[fill=gray!50] (225:{sqrt(3)}) -- (225:3) -- arc -- (-45:3) -- arc -- (-45:{sqrt(3)}) -- cycle;

\draw (0,0) circle (3);
\draw (0,0) circle ({sqrt(3)});

\draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (225:3) -- (45:3);
\draw (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\draw (135:3) -- (-45:3);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: explicitly `\shade (225:{sqrt(3)}) -- (225:3) arc (225:315:3) -- (315:{sqrt(3)}) arc (315:225:{sqrt(3)});` ?

Comment: @percusse   Yep.  Replace "`--`" with "`arc`."  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

converting comment :

```
\shade (225:{sqrt(3)}) 
       -- (225:3) arc (225:315:3) 
       -- (315:{sqrt(3)}) arc (315:225:{sqrt(3)});
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\shade (225:{sqrt(3)})
       -- (225:3) arc (225:315:3)
       -- (315:{sqrt(3)}) arc (315:225:{sqrt(3)});

\draw (0,0) circle (3)
      (0,0) circle ({sqrt(3)})

      (-3,0) -- (3,0)
      (225:3) -- (45:3)
      (0,-3) -- (0,3)
      (135:3) -- (-45:3)
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The four lines can also be generated by a `\foreach` loop, e.g.:

```
\draw
  % two circles

  \foreach \i in {0, ..., 3} {
    (\i*45:3) -- (\i*45 + 180:3)
  }
;
```